# Disabling SplitScreen mode in Nougat

Tags: android, frameworks, android-service, android-source, split-screen

How to disable the SplitScreen mode in Android 7.1.1 without disabling the MultiWindow mode?

I am using Freeform Window Mode to open multiple activities. In landscape orientation of device when an activitiy is dragged to the left or right edge of the screen the activity gets docked and the StackDivider splits the screen. Disabling MultiWindow mode eventually disables Freeform Window mode. So is there any way to disable the SplitScreen mode only (without disabling MultiWindow mode) by editing the Android source code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In freeform mode, when an application or window is moved left or right corner of the screen by dragging its `DecorCaptionView` a dim layer is generated either at left or right depending on the position of window and it get docked to the current dim side on  `MOtionEvent.ACTION_UP` event.

The `MotionEvent` actions on `DecorCaptionView` is handled by `frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/wm/TaskPositioner.java` and `moveTaskToDockedStack()` method in `ActivityManagerService` is invoked whenever a window gets docked. The `updateDimLayerVisibility()` method in `TaskPositioner.java` is responsible for the creation of dim layer. So the SplitScreen mode can be disabled by commenting out above mentioned two method calling lines in `TaskPositioner.java`.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/multi-window.html

As per documentation, do this in you manifest activity or application

```
android:resizeableActivity=["true" | "false"]
```